# Unable to switch to Java 1.6 on El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, osx-elcapitan

I'm running the following command to try to switch to Java 1.6

> $export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)

But am getting the error

> -bash: JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home:
>   No such file or directory

Yet the directory in the error message does exist:
[image]

Comment: When do you get that error? And does running just the `java_home` part return what's expected? It looks more like something that's using `JAVA_HOME` is confused.

Comment: It appears in the terminal immediately after running the $export command. What do you mean by running just the java_home part? If I run that command without the $export there's no error

Comment: Ah, ha; there's no `$export` command. There's an `export` command. The `$` is the default shell prompt. (Well, was; I don't see it much anymore IRL.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to leave the preceding dollar-sign off (`export` instead of `$export`):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)
```

Comment: Oh, lol, they're typing the actual `$`, I assumed it was `PS1`.